# Processing occasionally fails with "Unexpected end of file has occurred."

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

I've got an Analysis Services database that's used for reporting on email activity. It mainly counts incoming and outgoing messages, who they're to and from, etc.

Fact table: 11,367,910 rows
Address dimension table: 386,015 rows
To-address fact table: 21,303,290 rows (used for many-to-many intermediate measure group)
Date dimension table: 9,132 rows

It's a simple structure, but there's a lot of data in it. The two measure groups have 6 yearly partitions with varying numbers of rows in them. The whole thing takes about 30 minutes to process fully.

But that's not my problem (at least I don't think it is). Seemingly randomly, the scheduled processing task will fail with the error `Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: root, return, ExecuteResponse, soap:Body, soap:Envelope. Line 3707, position 1.` The line number can vary, but the error is the same. I've tried hunting around, but I can't find any info on what this indicates. Anybody else run into this error?

Comment: Can it be lack of disk space? [Related MSDN forums question.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/sqlanalysisservices/thread/89d7912e-bc12-4322-a73b-5abe737f4e22)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually managed to track this down to low memory. I was under the mistaken impression that 32-bit Analysis Services could use AWE memory, but alas it does not. I changed the processing strategy from full processing, to incremental processing of only the appropriate partitions. That seems to have reduced the memory requirements, and resolved the issue (hasn't failed in quite some time now).